# Jquery get Children with level

Tags: jquery

I want get child for element but only the child selector
For example:

`$(“#tree”).find('.list ul li a')`

I got all the children  and children  of children
There is the `children()` function, but this is just one level, and I want get children with more than one level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all children of a given object at any level, you can use this:

```
$("#tree").find("*");
```

If this is not what you want, then please clarify your question further so we can understand what you're asking.

Comment: I find the answer
$(element).find('>.list>ul>li')